# Trouble with Inheritance, getting NULL on some data from inherited class

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I have two classes. One is called person the other student. Student inherits from person.
Everything works fine until I fill out my form and pass the data to the next form for display.

Everything displays fine except the name, address and state. These are from the person class and have NULL values. What is driving me nuts is that city, zipcode and birthdate are from the same person class and work just fine. I am not seeing why this is happening and am hoping someone with more knowledge can point me in the right direction.

Here are the 2 classes:

```
public class Person
{
    private string name;
    private string address;
    private string city;
    private string state;
    private string zipcode;
    private DateTime birthdate;

    public Person()
    {
    }

    public Person(string name, string address, string city, string state, string zipcode, DateTime birthdate)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public string Address
    {
        get { return address; }
        set { name = address; }
    }

    public string City
    {
        get { return city; }
        set { city = value; }
    }
    public string State
    {
        get { return state; }
        set { state = value; }
    }

    public string Zipcode
    {
        get { return zipcode; }
        set { zipcode = value; }
    }

    public DateTime Birthdate
    {
        get { return birthdate; }
        set { birthdate = value; }
    }
}

public class Student : Person
{
    private string studentID;
    private double gradepointAverage;
    private List<string> currentClasses = new List<string>();

    public Student()
    {
    }

    public Student(string name, string address, string city, string state, string zipcode, DateTime birthdate, string studentID, double gradepointAverage, List<string> currentClasses)
        : base(name, address, city, state, zipcode, birthdate)
    {
        this.studentID = studentID;
        this.gradepointAverage = gradepointAverage;
        this.currentClasses = currentClasses;
    }

    public string StudentID
    {
        get { return studentID; }
        set { studentID = value; }
    }

    public double GradePointAverage
    {
        get { return gradepointAverage; }
        set { gradepointAverage = value; }
    }

    public List<string> CurrentClasses
    {
        get { return currentClasses; }
        set { currentClasses = value; }
    }
}
```

Here is where I instantiate the class:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        s = new Student();
        s.StudentID = txtStudentID.Text;
        s.Name = txtName.Text;
        s.Address = txtAddress.Text;
        s.City = txtCity.Text;
        s.State = txtState.Text;
        s.Zipcode = txtZipCode.Text;
        s.Birthdate = DateTime.Parse(txtBirthdate.Text);
        s.GradePointAverage = Convert.ToDouble(txtGradPoint.Text);


        string stringItmem;
        foreach(Object selectedItem in lstClasses.SelectedItems)
        {
            stringItmem = selectedItem as String;
            s.CurrentClasses.Add(stringItmem);
        }
        students.Add(s);
        resetForm();
        MessageBox.Show("Student has been saved.");
    }
```

Comment: Which constructor are you using to instantiate your `Student`? Are you using the one with all the parameters and passing all the parameters along to the base class? Did you try setting a break point and debugging the application?

Comment: I am instantiating Student s and then setting them individually. I used the debugger and it shows null in all of the mentioned fields. I set to break where I am passing Student s into a list of students and it is already null for them there.

Comment: So, is your problem that your Student's values are not being set properly from your input (i.e. should the values not be 'null'), or is it that the null values are being displayed incorrectly on the next form? Sorry, it is not clear from your question what exactly is your problem.

Comment: My input is not being properly set from the form. name, address and state show null even though data is entered. city, zipcode and birthdate from the same parent class work fine and show up in the display form. That's why I am so confused. Shouldn't they all have the same issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public string Address
{
    get { return address; }
    set { name = address; }   // Should be "address = value"
}
```

See the setter - what you're doing here is corrupting your `name` without setting the `address`. This should explain all your data corruption. Since you set `name` first in your code this explains why they're both `null`.

Comment: Yup... copy/paste wins(looses) again :)

Comment: dang I did not see that. Talking about not seeing the trees with a forest in the way. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

the problem with your address is that in the set you have it as `name = address` instead of `address = value;`

```
public string Address
{
    get { return address; }
    set { name = address; }
}
```